# How can I active a specific variable by having someone type in the variable name?

Tags: javascript, class

Working on a game and I want to have the specific variable appear and be printed in my alert feature if a user types in the name of the variable. How can I do that?

```
class Enemy {
    constructor(health, strength) {
        this.health = health;
        this.strength = strength;

        var Charizard = (350,100);
        var Venusaur = (250,200);
        var Blastortle = (200,250);
        var Pikachu = (110,275);
    }
}

var chosenEnemy = prompt("Choose enemy to battle");

if (chosenEnemy != 'Charizard' && chosenEnemy !=  'Vensaur' && chosenEnemy != 'Blastortle' &&   chosenEnemy != 'Pikachu') {
 alert("choose a valid enemy");
}

 alert(Enemy.health + " " + Enemy.strength);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store objects to help you with the variable name:

```
const Charizard = {
  name: 'Charizard',
  value: /* variable value here */
}
```

Of course you can have different expected string (coming from user) and variable name this way, which would be a better idea.